# We're sorry. We can't open XXX.docx because we found

Tags: microsoft-word

A word file I just saved will not open and show this error.

"We're sorry. We can't open XXX.docx because we found a problem with its contents"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may have to do with corruption of normal.dotm file corruption (it's the default styles file). Microsoft [suggests](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/were-sorry-we-cant-open-xxxdocx-because-we-found-a/a1f3ac1c-0459-4c51-bf32-7d94952684e1?auth=1) you can delete it and word will recreate it, so check that first.

But in my case, I changed my corrupt file extension form .docx to .zip

Now run Word 2013 and open this zip file and wallaha it opens the file. Now save it back to proper word file. This really is long story short from [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/a2e6011b-6185-49e1-b5ea-2f76c0ab32ef/word-docx-will-not-open?forum=officeitpro).

Answer (score 0):

I found that the use of a footer with Centre Align and Right Align tabs caused Word to do this
The details shows the error is in [image]
which was my clue as I had just changed the footer to try out the tab types

The document is saved to a OneDrive (which the link seems in the other answer seems to indicate is relevant) however moving the file from the OneDrive did not fix the problem

Clicking OK and saying yes recover the recovers the document without any problems - Yet if I save and reopen the error re-occurs - I've deleted the footer and recreated it and its ok now

Answer (score 0):

2 method worked for me

1. If you open the file in Wordpad it should open.
2. Convert the file into HTML and then convert back to Word, it should work